# Notice and remove erroneous spaces between letters in a word

Tags: r, pdf, tm

I have a text file that looks like:

```
These are the hig hlights. Transit ioning to this, hello. I have 
provided this informat ion. The man has this dis eas e. He needs to take this dos age of medicine. Fo r o ne mo nth, thro ug h this pro g ram, do this. Do no t overdose.
```

There are numerous words that are broken up. Is there any way to notice this errors in word structure and fix them through r?

So basically:

```
These are the highlights. Transitioning to this, hello. I have 
provided this information. The man has this disease. He needs to take this dosage of medicine. For one month, through this program, do this. Do not overdose.
```

I got the text from a pdf using the following code:

```
file <- 'C:/Project/Section/SubSection/text.pdf'
Rpdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))

corpus <- VCorpus(URISource(file), readerControl = list(reader = Rpdf))
corpus.array <- content(content(corpus)[[1]])

txt<- write(corpus.array, "C:/Project/Section/SubSection/text1.txt") 
readtext<- eval(readLines("C:/Project/Section/SubSection/text1.txt"))
```

This produced the text with awkward spacing. Is there a better way to convert a pdf to to text file?

Comment: Looks like there is no pattern to differentiate `blah blah` from `hig hlights`

Comment: @akrun Is there any way in r to find out if a word is spelled right? I just added blah blah, but they stand for any possible word. I replaced them with some real words now. So basically I'm looking for if there is code that can see "hig" or "highlights" and see that neither on their own is a full word, and then can look at the next continuous string either backward or forward and combine to get the the desired "highlights".

Comment: It's definitely not trivial. Say if `highlights` was split `high lights`, you would only know it was wrong from significant context.

Comment: I suspect that going back to the source of the text file is more likely to produce a method that can give you output with correct spaces (they were probably inserted in some export)

Comment: I got the text from a pdf using the following code:
 
 file <- 'C:/Project/Section/SubSection/text.pdf'
 Rpdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))
 corpus <- VCorpus(URISource(file), 
                   readerControl = list(reader = Rpdf))
 corpus.array <- content(content(corpus)[[1]])
 txt<- write(corpus.array, "C:/Project/Section/SubSection/text1.txt")
  readtext<- eval(readLines("C:/Project/Section/SubSection/text1.txt"))
  
 This produced the text with awkward spacing. Is there a better way to convert a pdf to to text file?